# Why can a lens be described by a fourier transform?

Tags: optics, fourier-transform, lenses

I am having a hard time understanding the theory behind why we can describe light passing through a lens to the focal plane as a Fourier transform and then an inverse Fourier transform. What is the reason why we can do this?

Comment: Some of the answers here may help. [Optics of the eye - do we see Fourier transforms?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/28711/37364). Also see Wikipedia - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_optics#Fourier_transforming_property_of_lenses and HyperPhysics - http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/optmod/fouropt.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An ideal lens will map any point source that emits spherical waves sitting in the focal plane into plane waves, in other words congruent rays will be parallel rays, and of course parallel rays, ie., plane waves will be mapped into a point on the focal plane. This is the same as the "Dirac delta function" is being mapped into a constant by a Fourier Transform and vice versa.