# What happens if you put a converging lens in front of a diffraction grating?

Tags: optics, diffraction

I mean a situation like this:
[image]

Thinking about the intensity function and maxima and minima, I don't really understand the use of a converging lens and what a difference focal distance does to the system. Could please explain?

Comment: this may also help [1](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/596774/why-can-a-lens-be-described-by-a-fourier-transform/596776?r=SearchResults&s=2%7C92.6113#596776) and [2](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/643740/does-a-lens-always-act-as-a-fourier-transform/643750#643750)

Comment: @hyportnex thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are incident plane waves which hit the diffraction grating and produce a set of secondary sources at the slurs which are in phase with one another.

The path $d$ difference between adjacent parallel rays as drawn in the diagram is $d\sin\theta$.

If those rays overlapped and the path difference was an integer times the wavelength of light there would be a maximum of intensity.
To make the rays overlap a lens is introduced which makes the rays overlap in the focal plane of the lens and a maximum intensity is produced at position $P$ if $d\sin\theta=n\lambda$.
The distance between the lens and its focal plane is the focal length of the lens.
So increasing the focal length of the lens will result in a focal plane which is further from the lens than before and a corresponding increase in the separation of the maxima.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clear explanation!